# Rooting a wiko jerry is impossible due to all fastboot commands lock the phone

Tags: rooting, fastboot, system-freeze

On Linux:

All fastboot commands lock. Particularly `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot flashing unlock`.

After removing and re-attaching the phone to the usb port (without turning it off), the phone becomes detectable on the usb, thus the usb connection handshake runs, but it is not listed in `fastboot devices` any more. The only way to fix the phone at this point is removing-reattaching the battery into it. I believe, it might be a full system freeze.

The usb id of the device is "fastboot Gadget", with the google vendor id.

On Windows, no fastboot driver was working (not the google and neither the mtk). They simply did not find the device.

I've seen also multiple limitations in the (not yet rooted) phone: for example, `adb shell` gets the shell as usual, but `/dev` is already forbidden.

I suspect, maybe the manufacturer has a dislike of rooting and it is a low-cost attempt to make it impossible. Is it possible? Where could I even start to find the cause of the problem?

*Extension:*

I could make the ADB fastboot driver working on Windows (with the Google driver in the the latest Android Sdk), and also the device was visible in fastboot mode. The result was essentially the same: usb-level lock requiring battery removal to make the phone usable again.

I tried it on multiple machines, and on multiple OSes, and the problem was always the same.

*Extension #2:*

To be clear: the device shows an mtk driver in adb mode, and a spreadtrum driver in fastboot. `fastboot oem unlock` locks the phone on a way that only removal of the battery can fix it. It happens on multiple machines, with multiple OSes. However, Wiko's own update tool, downloadable from [here](https://orirom.com/wiko-new-jerry-v2806-firmware/), works. It is a windows-only tool, capable to install only the Wiko's own updates. I am now playing with this tool, what it does and how. Maybe it can flash also a custom firmware. If it won't work, I will forever blacklist the company and throw the phone out.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks! 1) I long allowed it. "Enable OEM unlock" is on. 2) Ok I will do that, but honestly I wrote this post after a lot of futile attempts. 3) Yes, fastboot devices shows the connected device, everything is okay on the usb level, except any modification operation. | I will be back after yet another try. The important thing is: fastboot oem unlock *freezes the phone*, there is no error message or anything, it simply becomes completely unresponsive. My impression is that a firmware developer had exactly 5 minutes to disable any rootability and it was his quick&dirty solution.

Comment: @alecxs I hope, not this is the case. The phone is pretty well visible on the USB bus, both in fastboot and in adb mode, exactly until I try to do a `fastboot oem unlock` (in Linux). I will try the windows way again.

Comment: Wiko is one of the rarely brands which are in compliance with the GPL and provides Mediatek source code. I am pretty sure these devices are made unlockable

Comment: @alecxs I am sorry to say, but I can't see any goodness from the manufacturer side. This looks like: either a *very* mysterious and rare hardware problem, or an intentional action by the manufacturer to avoid rooting. Decide what is more likely.

Comment: @alecxs Now I am investigating, it seems it might require some specific tool for rooting, and not the ordinary fastboot method. Be back soon.

Comment: Investigation still in progress. My current best trace is this: https://orirom.com/wiko-new-jerry-v2806-firmware/ It seems to be exactly about my problem. Funny, but actually I can access my device on adb, and it is an mtk driver, only `fastbook oem unlock` hanged up the phone - even my process on my machine. That indicates a driver problem. On Windows, I had serious troubles from the beginning. Now I try these spreadtrum drivers - as I can see, they have no Linux version, unfortunately.

Comment: never used that tool, but here some more drivers maybe it helps https://androidmtk.com/download-spreadtrum-drivers

Comment: Okay. Bonus info: it shows an MTK device in adb operation. However, in fastboot mode, the USB ID of the device is 1782:5d06, which is a speadtrum. There is no Linux driver for that, and the fastboot tool talks with it directly over the usb socket. And this things goes somewhere bad.

Comment: @alecxs In the fastboot mode, I see a spreadtrum and not an mtk chip. Already `fastboot oem unlock` hanged the phone, before any flashing could have happened. I would be surprised if any such tool could work with spreadtrum chip. I think, if I succeed, then first I will root the phone, then I will be able to map the partition table and play with it as I think it the best. I don't think that any MTK-specific thing will ever work (_maybe_, some really hardcore thing, namely updating partitions as root, without fastboot)